# Join a single property/column from @EmbeddedId

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

is it possible, to join only a part of an embeddedId to another table as Foreign Key in Spring?

Comment: Why would you even need that?

Comment: I'm writing a tool, which is managing motions. The PKs of the motion-table consists of a ID and a date (when it was placed). If a motion will be changed, a new record will be written with the same ID and a new placed-date (to view changes like a GIT). Now you can comment a motion, too. And for linking a comment to a motion, I only need the motionID

Comment: I think you misunderstood the concept of the EmbeddedId then. It's used when you want to have composite identifiers. If you want to refer to an entity which has a composite identifier, then the referee should have the composite id as foreign key as well and not only just a part of it.

Comment: if your identifier is a composite and you want to have association with a table using one of the attributes of the key that leaves a possibility to map to more than one object is that a valid scenario for you? if so why not map to many and in your persistence logic create the association for every object with this part of identifier

Comment: Do you mean only with @JoinColumn instead of @JoinColumns?

Comment: facing the same issue